# Joomla - nooku framework - what is dispatch?

Tags: joomla

Someone work with nooku framework ?

with entry point

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
if(!defined('KOOWA')){
    JError::raiseWarning(0, JText::_("Koowa wasn't found. Please install the Koowa plugin and enable it."));
    return;
}
$view = KRequest::get('get.view', 'cmd', 'hellos');
echo "<pre>";
var_dump(KFactory::get('admin::com.hello.dispatcher'));

KFactory::get('admin::com.hello.dispatcher')->dispatch($view);
```

when var_dump i get a object , but i don't see dispatch()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see the dispatch() method because it doesn't exist indeed. Please see the KControllerAbstract:__call() method. It does all that magic. More on __call() method here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Answer (score 1):

It`s all about nooku magic!You don`t need to create dispatch.php on your root component folder unless you need to override default nooku dispatcher behaviour. 
default dispatcher is located on com_default and you will need to enter this code in it:

```
class ComMycomponentDispatcher extends ComDefaultDispatcherDefault {}
```

ComDefaultDispatcherDefault extends KDispatcherDefault extends KDispatcherAbstract which extends KControllerAbstract which extends KObject and implements KObjectIdentifiable.